# How to handle external users? use box enterprise events and AS-User content API

Tags: box-api, box

I have a use case of Box **External Users** and **AS-User** API.

I'm using Enterprise Events to track file-related events and then perform actions on those files. For Managed Users I can use AS-USER to perform these actions. But this does not work when events are triggered by External Users.

How can I get more information or perform actions on files owned by external users?

Comment: Hi Evans, it's unclear what you are asking. What are you trying to accomplish?

Comment: Hi John, thanks for your response. I'm trying to use [Enterprise Events](https://box-content.readme.io/reference#get-events-in-an-enterprise) Retrieves events like "EDIT" file. When I got this event, I want download file content. For Managed Users I can get user id from API result "created_by" . Then I will use [AS-USER](https://box-content.readme.io/reference#as-user-1) download file content. But when events triggered by External Users I cannot do the same thing in this case.